# How to have specific events fire if you can only bind ajaxStart to document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document.

I have two different forms on my page, both which I want to submit using ajax, and display a 'sending' while it's happening. I want `#contact_response` to display a message when the `#contact_form` is submitted like so:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#contact_response").html("Sending...");  
});
```

And similarly, `#booking_response` to display a message when `#booking_form` is submitted. However, doing this causes the other element to display `Sending...`. If you're only meant to attach `ajaxStart()` to the `document`, how are you meant to send multiple responses, but only update certain sections?

Is this the wrong function to use?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, xhr, options) {
    if (options.url === "targetedScriptPath") $("#contact_response").html("Sending..."); 
}).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, options) {
    if (options.url === "targetedScriptPath") $("#contact_response").empty(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know the `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxStop()` functions are good if you want to trigger something globally on your page when some ajax-action is going on.
i ran over a similar problem, and that's how i solved it:
just trigger the action with the event that submits your form (maybe some click-event) or add an event-listener for the form submission like for example:

```js
$('#contact_form').on("submit", function() {
    $("#contact_response").html("Sending...");
});
$('#booking_form').on("submit", function() {
    $("#booking_response").html("Sending...");
});
```

to trigger the action after the ajax function has been completed, use the callback-function of whatever ajax function you are using:

```
$.post("booking_update.php", {
        //post vars
        post_var1: post_text
    }, 
    function(result) {
        //callback function
        $("#booking_response").html("Success!");
    }
);
```